# silverlight enabled wcf service retuning value

Tags: silverlight, dialog

This is my service which checks username and password

```
   [OperationContract]

    public bool LoginCheck(string username, string password) 
    {
        RoadTransDataContext db = new RoadTransDataContext();

        var _Pass = (from d in db.users where d.username == username select d.password).SingleOrDefault();

        if (_Pass == password)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And this is child window

```
 private void LoginCheckCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference.LoginCheckCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Log = e.Result;
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference.ServiceClient webservice = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient();

        webservice.LoginCheckCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference.LoginCheckCompletedEventArgs>(LoginCheckCompleted);
        webservice.LoginCheckAsync(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Password);

        if (_Log == true)
        {
            this.DialogResult = true;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

problem is that `LoginCheckCompleted` method is calling when `OKButton_Click` method finished. so if it input correct username, pass and press button it doing nothing if i click onece again window closing

Comment: By the way, the code size of the service method can be reduced: `return db.users.Where(d => d.username == username && d.password == password).Any();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight uses the async model of invoking web services and it takes some time to wait until the response is returned. In your example the assigment `_Log = e.Result;` will be called, let's assume, after 1-2 seconds, whereas the check `if (_Log == true)` will be called immideately and of course before the assignment.

That's why you should put all the necessary code in the callback and remove all the code after the async call. I've fixed it for you:

```
private void LoginCheckCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference.LoginCheckCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _Log = e.Result;

    if (_Log == true)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}

private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference.ServiceClient webservice = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient();

    webservice.LoginCheckCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference.LoginCheckCompletedEventArgs>(LoginCheckCompleted);
    webservice.LoginCheckAsync(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Password);
}
```